# Why can't I assign the result of a query to a variable when using Room?

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to put the result of a query into a variable to be used later on in my activity. I can put the results into a Log message but the variable is always null.

I ended up putting the result into a Textview but I would like to know why I can't just use the result?

Activity

```
Integer integer1; 
 mClothingViewModel.getTotalIds().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer integer) {

                integer1 = integer;

            }
        });
```

Model

```
LiveData<Integer> getTotalIds() { return mTotalIds;}
```

Repo

```
   int getGetIntTotalClothes () {

        return mGetIntTotalClothes;
    }
```

Dao

```
 @Query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Clothes ORDER BY COUNT(id)")
    LiveData<Integer> getTotalNumClothes();
```

I researched and tried to use the Asynctask however I kept getting the "Cannot run on main thread" error.

Any explanation would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Where do you "put value into variable"?

Comment: Ah I changed the code under activity to properly reflect what I was trying to do

Comment: My guess that is because you Room gives you LiveData. Meaning that it can take some time before you receive the result. The reason why it "works" with the TextView IS that once results of the query is resolved it sets to the text view.

Comment: How can I make my program wait to get the result? Is there a better way to be able to store the value of the query into a variable?

Comment: Well, you can change the return type of the query in the room(LiveData<Integer> -> Integer). But I wouldn't recommend it, because then it will block the thread. If you have to do some loading in the background before actually having some values to show then show some progress bar(loading circle).

Comment: Can you please give an example?  I have been trying to get this working for the past 3 days and have been going around in circles